# Telerik Reporting Styles

Tags: telerik, styles, telerik-reporting

I have just started messing with Telerik Reporting in an MVC C# application.

Since I need to create a dozen of reports, I was asked to create an external style to be aplied to all of them.

I cannot understand how it works, how to set the rules...

**Eg** I can create a style to affect all HtmlTextBoxes **BUT** I am trying to create a rule to have all the HtmlTextBoxes contained in the  Group Header  having (lets say) blue Background, Bold Segoi Font and I cannot.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> Styles created in a Telerik Report can be exported and then used in other reports.
>   You can store one or more Styles in an exported file.
>   The exported information is stored in an XML file.

So you can create your style rules using the Style context menu Right-clicking on the report object.
[Style exporting and reusing style sheets](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/style-exportingand-reusing-style-sheets)

Use various Style Selectors to define how a style will be applied globally to items in a report. Each Style Rule that you create (either in code or using the StyleRule Collection Editor) must be created as one of the basic four selector.
[Learn more about style selector..](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/style-understanding-style-selectors)
 For me the best one is the "StyleSelector" that behave like a Css Class.

Nb: 
You can manage and bind your extenal StyleSheet in code behind.
Or in your calling application.

```cs
this.StyleSheet.Clear();
this.ExternalStyleSheets.Add(
    new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.ExternalStyleSheet("baseThemeRpt.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the Descendant Type